# Duplicate PCI device id (lspci -nn)

Tags: pci-express

I have two identical network cards installed in my system (same device, same vendor).

Now I wanted to stub one network card in order to use PCIe passthrough.

I've come to realize that the two network cards have identical device ids:

```
$ lspci -nn
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8161] (rev 15)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8161] (rev 15)
```

As you can see the PCI device id `10ec:8161` is the same for **both** network cards. I expected them to be different (i.e. that each network card has its own unique PCI device id).

Is this normal behaviour? How would I go about just stubbing one of the two network cards (using `vfio-pci`) ? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a device ID but a *product* ID – `10ec` is the PCI [vendor ID](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10ec) for Realtek and `8161` is the product or model ID for their "RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller".  It is not a serial number and is not supposed to be unique, quite the opposite.

The unique "bus ID" of each card on your PCI bus is the *leftmost* column, with `[0000:]02:00.0` being your first card and `03:00.0` being the second. Most tools dealing with PCI reference devices by their bus ID, which usually remains stable as long as the topology doesn't change, e.g. a card installed in that specific slot is going to remain 03:00.

(The format of a bus ID as shown by lspci is "[domain:]bus:device.function".)

Your lspci output does not contain any globally unique ID; in fact I'm not sure whether PCI devices generally have one. (Running `sudo lspci -v` appears to show a capability "[13c] Device Serial Number:" for some devices, but not all of them.)

---

If I understand correctly, writing a VID:PID to the "new_id" file of a PCI driver only *allows* that driver to be bound to matching devices, but doesn't actively kick out any other drivers (i.e. you still have to unbind each device from its original driver and bind it to vfio-pci). Looking at [DPDK's tools](https://github.com/ceph/dpdk/blob/master/tools/dpdk-devbind.py#L400), the latter part is still done by bus ID:

```
echo 10ec 8161 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id
[...]
echo 0000:03:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/unbind
echo 0000:03:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/bind
```

Comment: First of all: thank you so much for this _very_ quick reply! I tried to find some information about PCI identifiers in general, but I found it _very_ hard to find anything :/ Ok. So if that "id" is to identify a _product_ and not a _device_ is it even possible to stub just one of the two network cards [if they're identical]? (for example with `vfio-pci.ids=...`)

Comment: Not sure, but if the usage docs at https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/vfio.html#vfio-usage-example show the device being manually unbound from its original driver by bus ID, wouldn't it be possible to also manually bind the same device to vfio-pci using some form of `echo 03:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/bind`? (It seems [that's what DPDK does.](https://github.com/ceph/dpdk/blob/master/tools/dpdk-devbind.py))